# How to add ADDITIONAL url parameters to my mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Ok so here is the problem

I have about 30 or so rewrite rules that look like this:

```
    RewriteRule ^Frequently-Asked-Questions$ index.cfm?event=faqs-frequently-asked-questions 
    RewriteRule ^faq/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.cfm?event=faq&faqID=$2
```

So this works great and urls like:

```
    www.example.com/Frequently-Asked-Questions
```

or
        www.example.com/faq/why-wont-this-work/1234

Work perfectly.

The problem is when we try to add URL parameters on TOP of this, so

```
    www.example.com/Frequently-Asked-Questions?phoneNum=123-345-2322 doesn't work at all.
```

How can i add these extra url parameters universally across the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the `QSA` & `L` flag at the end.

Flag [`QSA` <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)
Flag [`L` <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

```
RewriteRule ^Frequently-Asked-Questions$ index.cfm?event=faqs-frequently-asked-questions [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^faq/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.cfm?event=faq&faqID=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: does not work, it keeps splitting the index.html removind the params and doing an internal redirect