# RewriteRule Does Not Yield Expected Substitution

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Everything is going perfect.  It looks like it understands what I want, but then something I can't understand begins to happen. My .htaccess looks like this:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^contacts/edit(new|existing)$ /index.php?route=contacts/edit$1 [NC,L,QSA]

The first relevant line in the log is ->

[Wed Apr 07 14:23:41.495232 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2302] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:13883] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#209cc4c8][rid#23090058/initial] [perdir /path/to/document/root/] rewrite 'contacts/editNew' -> '/index.php?route=contacts/editNew', referer: http://localhost/

- Comment: It looks at the request URI and attempts to substitute it to 'index.php?route=...'

Line #2 ->

[Wed Apr 07 14:23:41.495256 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2302] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:13883] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#209cc4c8][rid#23090058/initial] split uri=/index.php?route=contacts/editNew -> uri=/index.php, args=route=contacts/editNew, referer: http://localhost/

- Comment: It tries to split the uri into URI and parameters.

Line #3 ->

[Wed Apr 07 14:23:41.495283 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2302] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:13883] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#209cc4c8][rid#23090058/initial] [perdir /document/root/path/] trying to replace prefix /path/to/document/root/ with /, referer: http://localhost/

- Comment: mod_rewrite just translates the DOCUMENT_ROOT path to "/".

Line #4 ->

[Wed Apr 07 14:23:41.495311 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2302] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:13883] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#209cc4c8][rid#23090058/initial] [perdir /path/to/document/root/] trying to replace context docroot /path/to/document/root with context prefix , referer: http://localhost/

- Comment: I do not know what this is.  I would like someone to, please, explain what is going on in this line. Strangely, there is a space between prefix and the comma.  Does this mean anything?

Line #5 ->

[Wed Apr 07 14:23:41.495334 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2302] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:13883] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#209cc4c8][rid#23090058/initial] [perdir /path/to/document/root/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT], referer: http://localhost/

- Comment: This is the redirect to /index.php, which I believe is correct.

Line #6 ->

[Wed Apr 07 14:23:41.495834 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2302] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:13883] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#209cc4c8][rid#23091b18/initial/redir#1] [perdir /path/to/document/root/] strip per-dir prefix: /path/to/document/root/index.php -> index.php, referer: http://localhost/

- Comment: I believe this is taking an absolute URL path and making it relative.  Is this standard?  Do you have to specify this in your code or does it happen by default?

Line #7 ->

[Wed Apr 07 14:23:41.495900 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2302] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:13883] ::1 r- - [localhost/sid#209cc4c8][rid#23091b18/initial/redir#1] [perdir /path/to/document/root/] applying pattern '^contacts/edit(new|existing)$' to uri 'index.php', referer: http://localhost/

- Comment: This is what has got me puzzled.  '^contacts/edit(edit|existing)$' is applied to uri 'index.php', but not to 'index.php?route=contacts/edit$1', which is what, I believe, I have indicated in my second rewrite rule.  So, why doesn't this occur??

Finally, and I have no idea why this happens, the entire URL gets translated to "http://contacts/editnew"!  Even localhost gets removed.

I would really appreciate if you could help me out with this.

Comment: _“is applied to uri 'index.php', but not to 'index.php?route=contacts/edit$1'”_ - a RewriteRule matches the pattern against the _path_ component of the URL only.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish two things. #1.  Keep the pretty URL, which is the same as the requested URL(in this case localhost/contacts/editNew).  #2  Translate the pretty URL to localhost/index.php?route=contacts/editNew.  I need to know two things: how do I fix my rewrite rules so that this occurs and what does my script need to look like as far as the URL is concerned.  Please help.

Comment: I just found a question from several years ago by someone trying to do pretty much the exact same thing and he didn't get an answer.  Does this mean that what I'm doing here is unusual or does it mean that it's really, really hard? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136898/how-to-add-additional-url-parameters-to-my-mod-rewrite-rules

Comment: Just to provide additional details: after I try to load the homepage (just localhost/) I get "applying pattern '^contacts/listby(bldg|agency|lastname)$' to uri '' ".  (NOTE: the '' inside the quotation is a null string).  Does this mean that it tries to apply this pattern to anything?

Comment: I think "applying" doesn't equal "rewrite" so it could be that it's just looking...

Comment: I just saw this example on a webpage: RewriteRule /products/([0-9]+) /siteengine/products.php?id=$1.  It's very similar to mine. It works.  Does my pattern need to be more general?  Does it not work because it's too specific?

Comment: _“Does this mean that it tries to apply this pattern to anything?”_ - yes, of course, otherwise - how would it know, when the pattern actually matches?

Comment: _“the entire URL gets translated to "http://contacts/editnew"! Even localhost gets removed.”_ - can’t see why that would be happening. Can you remove the / in front of the target, so `index.php?route=contacts/edit$1`, and see if that changes anything?

Comment: I fixed by adding a ^index.php$ - [L] line ON TOP before any rewrite conditions and it's working now.